# Looking for a free MySQL Profiler?

Tags: php, mysql, ssms, profiler

I had become quite good at using to the profiler from Microsoft SSMS. I had looked into finding a similar tool for MySQL but actually most of the tools I've found are quite old and semi-functional. Is there anything out there that works fairly well without having to use command line? I've checked some REALLY old posts on stack overflow but leading to some dead-ends.

Comment: `<troll>` The best profiler is probably the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28764). You can use it to migrate from MySQL to SQL Server and use SQL Server's profiling tools. Although, realistically, once you "upgrade" from MySQL your performance problems will likely disappear. `</troll>`

Comment: Haha, very nice. Unfortunately I will be keeping my open source projects with open source databases. A cheap/free solution would be appreciated. I do love SSMS though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some searching, I thought I found something when I came across SQL Yog. Truthfully, it wasn't quite the answer I needed. I ended up using WinCacheGrind and KCacheGrind

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/

http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

They're interesting and helped me identify slower parts in the programming. Was a useful approach but is challenging to set up. It would be worthwhile for anyone who is interested.